# does netbeans include phpdocumentator?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

does netbeans include phpdocumentator so you can comment your code?

is there some guide on how to use it, eg. how should i comment, how to read them and how to print them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't, but this link contains step-by-step instructions for setting it up.

https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/generating_php_documentation_from_netbeans

Comment: i tested to comment a method in netbeans using the phpdoc comments and then i tried using the method with $object->run() and it displayed the  comments according to phpdoc way (included the @comments) so that means phpdoc is included in netbeans?

Comment: Perhaps the similarity of phpdoc to javadoc syntax means that netbeans is confused and thinks that they are the same.

Comment: Quick tip: put the cursor above any function or class, type /**[ENTER] and netbeans will insert a PHPdoc template, intelligently reading the parameters

Answer (score 2):

I think the actual PHPDocumentor tool can be installed from PEAR. I doubt it would be included with Netbeans. I imagine Netbeans provides a way to make use of that facility once installed.

Comment: it would be nice if sun included it in netbeans. why dont they? this seems like a default feature a major IDE should have out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE's ability to interpret your docblocks is built in to NetBeans and Eclipse, and probably other IDEs.  That's not phpDocumentor working for you (but close I suppose).

Having phpDocumentor installed would mean having the ability to generate API docs from your code and its docblocks.